# Photos back to iPhoto?

Tags: macos, photos.app, photos

Is there a way to get iPhoto back after installing Photos? When I upgraded to Yosemite 10.10.3, it installed Photos. I am not really liking the format or the design.

Answer (score 2):

iPhoto is a separate application from Photos (though if you had iPhoto on your dock, the 10.10.3 upgrade replaced its icon with Photos). You can still run it by using Spotlight or going to your Applications folder.

When you do run it, it may ask if you actually meant to open it, or if you meant to open Photos - choose the option to continue opening iPhoto. Your iPhoto library is still there and has not been removed. Keep in mind any changes made to your iPhoto library will not be reflected in Photos, so if you decide later that you *do* want to use Photos, you will need to create a new library in Photos to convert your iPhoto library at that time.

Answer (score 1):

If you open Spotlight and search for iPhoto, you should be able to still open it. Apple has discontinued development on it, however, and you could theoretically run into problems down the road if you keep using it. Apple probably won't ever straight up delete the application from your harddrive, but if you ever reformat, an OS X reinstall of 10.10.3 or later will not include iPhoto, but just the Photos app.

Comment: iPhoto was never included in the OS. It is part of iLife, which once installed provided updates separately under iPhoto. It should theoretically still be able to be downloaded from the Purchases tab in the Mac App Store if removed from the computer (though I'm not going to test it to find out).

Comment: I completely forgot about that. It is theoretically possible for apple to remove the ability to download pre-purchased apps (they've done it with certain OS releases in the past) but I imagine it's unlikely they would remove the ability to redownload iPhoto. I just checked and I am still able to download iPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in the last paragraph, I wrote the other paragraphs because I believe  the things I tried could work for others.

Im not an Apple snob or have 500 hits - just a person who buys thousands of dollars of Apple products. Im just a mom who loved iPhoto because I could easily rate pictures, create albums and drag and drop between albums. I recently purchased the 2015 Macbook just to have more memory for all the kids Apple Photobooks.

My shiny new space gray Macbook came with iPhoto..... until I chose the "System Update." All of a sudden iPhoto had a cross out sign and "Photos" showed up in the dock. So, naturally, I reset the mac back to factory settings. This may work for you.  Well guess what, iPhoto was now completely gone! iPhoto was not not in my spotlight or apps folder. So frustrating. Then I tried a new idea from forums - I went to the App store and planned to pay any amount of money for  iPhoto.  iPhoto was not in the app store - as some of the gurus below stated, I should get used to it as Apple aint going back. Well, I tried had tried Pages and Appeture with the "get use to it" attitude so I didn't give up since Apple finally realized that those apps were subpar. BTW every time I type "iphoto" it self corrects to "iPhoto." Whatever.

I was this close to returning this new Macbook for another new Macbook just to get iPhoto back...and promised myself never, never, never update again.

Then I tried one last theory... I went to my former application purchases. See photo below. It is where you purchased WWF and Kindle. And there I found that I had purchased iPhoto back in 2011! I then clicked install and wha la - iPhoto is back! Yay! Photo stream - something I hated, I welcomed back with open arms of unconditional love.