# Is there a way to disable/hide the new Photos App in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I prefer iPhoto over the new Photos app in Yosemite. It also annoys me, because every time I connect a new device to my Mac, I have to disable "Open Photos App when connected to this device" for that device. It also uses a spot from in my Launchpad.

**Is there any way to disable/hide the new Photos App in Yosemite from the launchpad and disable it from starting up if any new device connects?**
I don't want to delete it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photos back to iPhoto?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181866/photos-back-to-iphoto)

Comment: No, my question is about removing it, not about getting the photos back from the Photos App to iPhoto.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running this command from **Terminal**:
`defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ImageCapture disableHotPlug -bool YES`

To re-enable it again, type:
`defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ImageCapture disableHotPlug -bool NO`

Just a warning that I don't have access to a **Yosemite** machine to verify this.

Comment: What does this exactly do?

Comment: Disables Photos from launching when a device that captures images, like an iPhone, is connected.